# Trouble setting up Datatables with XAMPP

Tags: xampp, datatables

I am trying to install the DataTables plugin on my machine, but I cannot locate, not even in the DataTables Forums where to install it when using a platform like XAMPP.  I have extracted the DataTables-1.9.1 folder, but I don't know where to place it in my C:\XAMPP directory.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the datatables folder inside the directory served up by XAMPP, then in the html for the page add a `<script>` tag to pull in the DataTables js script

look inside datatables -> media -> js for a file called something like jquery.dataTables.js

Comment: Okay, so it goes in the top level folder, in my case `C:\xampp\`, the same as my `htdocs` or `sql` folders? That is simple.  Do I need to rename it from `DataTables-1.9.1` to just DataTables` or does it not matter?

Comment: @cquadrini not totally familar with xampp but it might be C:\xampp\www that you want to put it in.  you don't have to rename the datatables folder, but it might help it look prettier and easier to type out

Comment: unlike WAMP, there is no `C:\xampp\www.`  But I can play with the folder placement and see what happens.  Thank you for your help.